# Qual tamanho de um endereço de memória?

Tags: memória, alocação

Qual tamanho de um endereço de memória?

Eu penso que um endereço de memoria tem 32 bits, mas estou vendo em um *debugger* um `int`, onde separou 4 endereços para ele.

Então, um endereço equivale a 32 bits? Porque separou 4 endereços sendo que 32 bits já dá 4 bytes?

Comment: Mostre como está, dê mais detalhes, está difícil entender do que você está falando. Talvez esteja usando termos errados. Coloque código, resultado, *screenshot*, algo que indique melhor o que você quer.

Comment: O tamanho do inteiro é uma coisa, o tamanho do endereço é outra (e depende da arquitetura/plataforma usada), a alocação de memória e o alinhamento são outra coisa. Melhor você [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais detalhes, para que as pessoas possam entender qual é a dúvida e ajudar melhor.

Comment: Alexsander, vi que você postou outra pergunta praticamente igual. Tem alguma coisa que ainda não ficou clara nas respostas?

Comment: Sim por exemplo no meu computador os endereços  de 64 bits então baixei um crack-me para treinar minhas habilidades de engenharia reversa , então a key tem 15 caracteres de tamanho e tipo ocupa 4 endereços de 64 bits , sendo que a key e so 15 de tamanho  por isso na entendi.

Comment: Continua difícil entender sua dúvida! Você tem um screenshot desse debugger? Como sabe que é um int que está nesses 4 endereços? Tente [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais detalhes, está todo mundo com dificuldade de te entender...

Comment: @AlexsanderBorgesdamaceno se alguma das respostas fornecidas atenderam suas necessidades você pode aceitar ela. Isto vale para qualquer pergunta que você fez. E você pode votar em todas as respostas e perguntas que achar úteis. Isto vale para todo o *site*, não só coisas suas. Veja como funciona em [tour].

Comment: Acho a pergunta totalmente aceitável. Interpreto dessa maneira: "qual é o tamanho máximo de endereço?", considerando os offsets (resultado: resposta do pmargreff). Voto para reabri-la

Answer (score 4):

Os modelos diferem de arquitetura para arquitetura, quando você diz que tem um endereço de memória de 32 bits, o processador opera e tem instruções de 32 bits. 
Utilizando a arquitetura do microprocessador MIPS temos.

[image: Instrução geral MIPS]

Ou seja:

- 6 bits para o código da operação
- 26 bits para instruções

Dentro das instruções ainda podemos dividir em mais partes dependendo o tipo de instrução. E quando se começa a utilizar simuladores geralmente se divide está informação em mais pedaços. 
No seu caso pode estar acontecendo o seguinte, você pode ter utilizado um undereço de entrada inteiro pensando estar passando apenas seu inteiro, mas está fazendo uma operação completa.

Exemplo: `ori $t1, $t2, 0x4`

Não Entrarei em detalhe, mas de modo geral a instrução tem o seguinte formato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso se dá ao fato de as instruções na maioria (não todas) as vezes serem feitas em cima do sistema numérico Hexadecimal.

O que pode estar acontecendo é que você pode estar confundindo passar um dado para a memória com passar uma instrução.

Então tenha certeza de estar escrevendo apenas o dado, e não a instrução completa. Mas há uma grande possibilidade de como comentado na outra resposta o seu simulador estar dividindo sua palavra em bytes.

Gostaria de melhor especificação, de simulador, e assembly para qual processador está simulando.

Comment: Opa amigo estou usando x86 da intel , estou estudando sobre engenharia reversa , e tipo estou tentando descobrir um serial de 15 numeros e tipo tem 4 endereços reservados so para quardar o serial , bom tipo cada endereço na minha arquitetura tem 64-bits então porque o programa separou a key  em 4 endereços , sendo que uma variavel (int)  tem 4 bytes?

Comment: @AlexsanderBorgesdamaceno Se puder, edite sua pergunta original e acrescente estes detalhes de arquitetura, assim fica mais fácil das pessoas responderem. Nem todo mundo vai procurar os detalhes nos comentários.

Answer (score 3):

Está um pouco confuso. Você precisa aprender e usar o termos corretos para sabermos direito o que você está falando.

Em computador rodando em arquitetura 32 bits terá um endereço de 32 bits. Note que computadores com 64 bits podem rodar neste modo de endereçamento. Com 32 bits você pode acessar até 4GB de memória que é 2 elevado a 32. Quando não precisa acessar todo o espaço de endereçamento que a arquitetura permite usa-se apenas o que é necessário para economizar espaço já que cada endereço utilizado, e muitos são utilizados em uma aplicação grande, ocupa a quantidade de *bytes* do seu tamanho.

Muitas vezes usamos o termo "tamanho da palavra" para indicar que o tamanho do que você chama endereço de memória. A palavra é o tamanho do registrador do processador. É comum a palavra ser do mesmo tamanho do registrador, mas não é obrigatório.

Cada *byte* tem 8 bits, então para representar um endereço de memória precisaria de 32 bits.

Normalmente um inteiro costuma ter o tamanho da palavra do processador, portanto equivale ao tamanho do endereço de memória.

Se você diz que separou em 4 endereços (o termo parece estar errado), talvez ele tenha separado em 4 *bytes*. Talvez tenha separado em 4 *bytes* em formato hexadecimal. Se realmente existem 4 valores inteiros, cada um com 4 *bytes*, precisa descobrir o que está mostrando, deve haver um motivo, **se** está mostrando isto.

Mas objetivamente sua pergunta está respondida: em espaço de endereçamento de 32 *bits* o tamanho do endereço é 4 *bytes*. Assim como em espaço de endereçamento de 64 *bits* é 8 *bytes*, em espaço de endereçamento de 16 *bits* é 2 *bytes e em espaço de endereçamento de 8 *bits* é 1 *byte*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).