# É possível utilizar o tipo de dados DOUBLE em sistemas de 32-bit?

Tags: mysql, tipagem, double, 64-bits, 32-bits

O tipo de dados `DOUBLE` é um ponto flutuante de 64-bit, porém é possível utilizar em sistemas de 32-bit sem qualquer problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É possível, são coisas completamente distintas. Esse [32 bits indica a capacidade de endereçamento de memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54769/101), ou seja, ele chega até 4GB. Podemos dizer que é o tamanho do [ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57006/101) ou da [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101) (grosso modo).

Esse 64 do [`double`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101) é o tamanho do número que pode ser armazenado naquele tipo.

É só uma coincidência existir um tipo de 64 bits e uma arquitetura de 64 bits, não há relação entre essas medidas. Uma arquitetura 64 bits pode ser mais eficiente para lidar com um tipo `double`.

Bancos de dados, normalmente, armazenam dados de forma independente da arquitetura da máquina para que eles sejam portáveis entre computadores totalmente diferentes e entregam de forma que a arquitetura pede.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sua ultima edição foi bem esclarecedora. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

### Possível usar: sim

Como já comentado, um `double` é apenas a especificação de tamanho e de comportamento de um número de ponto flutuante ocupando 32 bits de espaço. Se o comportamento existir nativamente no processador então o processador será usado diretamente, senão então o comportamento será emulado pro software.

Ou seja, usar o `double` em qualquer CPU é possível. Ainda mais com a especificação IEEE 754 sendo de fato implementada em todo lugar.

### Sem qualquer problema: não

No entanto você *não* pode esperar que números de ponto flutuante funcionem de forma idêntica entre dois computadores não idênticos.

Isso ocorre basicamente por dois motivos:

1. CPUs podem fazer a conta com mais ou menos precisão interna nos passos intermediários. Só no final da conta que o número é padronizado para ter o tamanho e a forma da especificação. Mas o resultado final pode (e provavelmente vai) variar entre máquinas.
2. CPUs de 32 bits provavelmente só operam atomicamente com palavras de 32 bits. Isso tem uma consequência um tanto inesperada, que os números de 64 bits podem aparecer "quebrados" em CPUs de 32 bits.

Imagine que você tem uma classe ou estrutura com um campo `float64`, e onde três threads operam sem parar, da seguinte forma:

- A thread 1 sempre grava +1 no campo.
- A thread 2 sempre grava -2 no campo.
- A thread 3 lê o campo e decide o que fazer, mas aborta se tiver um número não mapeado.

Eis que numa CPU 64 bits esse código nunca abortará, mas numa CPU 32 bits você pode esperar que o programa morra de quando em quando.

Pela simples razão que de vez em quando a thread 3 as vezes vai ler um "número" que é formado pela metade dos bits de `(double)+1` e pela outra metade dos bits de `(double)-2`. E um número com esses bits não é nem `+1` e nem `-2`.

Comment: Essa parabola das três threads não faz sentido, o kernell dos OS além do threads fornecem outras primitivas de sincronização e bloqueio que nos permite estabelecer a atomicidade da operações.

Comment: Com acréscimo de bloqueio e sincronização é possível garantir a atomicidade de operações. Porém a pergunta não inclui essa condição. Pelo contrário, a pergunta é sobre quais problemas pode encontrar ao usar double em 32 bits. Eis um problema.

Comment: Estou tentando digerir, essa é uma situação onde certamente terminará um deadlock mas não por conta da arquitetura mas sim pela proposital ausência de um controles de concorrência como mutex, semáforos e seções críticas.